# How to find a function which provides the following condition

Tags: functions

> How to find $f$ function such that $$f(1)=1, f(2)=3$$

Comment: A linear function will do.

Comment: There are lots. Which one do you want?

Comment: Dear Randal, the simplest and most compact :)

Comment: If the domain is $\mathbb{N}$, you can define $f(n)$ as the number of the non-empty subsets of the set $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ :)

Comment: You’ve just found one.

Comment: The simplest and most compact is doubtlessly $f\colon\{1,2\}\to\{1,3\}$ defined by $f(1):=1$ and $f(2):=3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear interpolation polynomial:
$$f(x)=1\cdot\frac{x-2}{1-2}+3\cdot\frac{x-1}{2-1}=-(x-2)+3(x-1)=2x-1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: A linear function $f(x)=ax+b$ will do:

You must solve a system: $$a+b = 1$$
$$ 2a+b=3$$
to get $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2):

You have two points $(1,1)$ and $(2,3)$

You may use the point slope formula to find the equation of a straight line passing through your points .

Answer (score 1):

For example you can take
$$f(x)=a(x-1)+f(1)$$

with

$$f(2)=a+1=3$$

Or

$$f(x)=\cos(\pi x)+2$$

Comment: Or let $D=\{1,2\}$ and  take $f(1):=\min(D)$ and $f(2):=\sum_{a\in D}a$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1;& x = 1\\
3;& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I laughed.......

Answer (score 0):

Let $\pi(n)$ be the $n$-th prime number.  Define 
$$f(x)=\frac{\pi(2x+4)-\pi(2x+3)}{2}.$$